# qmake: using defines as conditionals

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

How can I define variables to be used in the qmake .pro file? For instance:

```
DEFINES += MYCONDITION # also used in C++ code
MYCONDITION {
   # do something here
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use CONFIG

```
CONFIG += qt console newstuff
newstuff {
    SOURCES += new.cpp
    HEADERS += new.h
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `CONFIG += MYCONDITION` if you want to create a conditional in the project file and `DEFINES` to create a conditional for header and cpp files(USING `#ifdef` etc)