# qmake conditional for RaspberryPi

Tags: c++, linux, qt, raspberry-pi, qmake

I'm trying to make a qmake .pro file to compile in RaspberryPi (not for cross compile). Can I use conditionals definitions depending on the platform:

```
linux-g++-64: {
    message(We are in Linux 64 bits)
}
macx: {
    message(we are in mac osX)
}
win32: ...
```

But I can't find a way to detect when I'm in a PaspberryPi with raspbian.

I have tried something like `linux-arm`, `arm-linux`, `linux-arm-gnueabi-g++` but not luck.

Someone know the correct way to make this conditional definitions or how to detect if we are compiling in a RaspberryPi architecture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [qmake: using defines as conditionals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670326/qmake-using-defines-as-conditionals)

Comment: @Troyseph Thakns for te link but I think that it is not the same, in the other post the "variable" is fixed in the .pro file. in my case I want to do externally because I want the same .pro file for X86 and ARM architecture.

Comment: I marked the question as a duplicate because you are both asking for the same functionality (in slightly different ways) and the answers on that question help you to achieve your goals. Whilst not a direct duplicate, linking the two questions is both helpful to you and future users.

Comment: As I learnt from you, it is possible to add `CONFIG` and `DEFINES` variables when calling `qmake` so your `.pro` file will still be the same for all platforms.

Comment: @Troyseph yes this is the point, you have only one .pro and it is valid for all S.O or platforms, normally you can detect if it is a Windows, or unix even a mac, but I can't detect if I'm in a intel linux or in a arm linux(raspberrypi in my case) so the only way that I have found to do is passing some flag in the qmake command.

Comment: curious if you ever shifted to cross-compile and how one might setup the .pro file

Comment: @tofutim not, I'm still compiling in the target, but for sure you can use what I'm using  look to my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
linux {
    contains(QMAKE_HOST.arch, arm.*):{
        raspberry's bla bla bla

    }else{
        ...
    }
}
```

I hope it works for you.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-host

Comment: Just in case, this will work if you build app on raspberry-pi. This is not suitable for cross compile.

Comment: For cross compile case you can use this check `contains(QMAKE_CXX, .*raspbian.*arm.*)` (since your QMAKE_CXX will look like `~/.../tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`)

Answer (score 1):

current Raspbian OS(32bit) for RPi3 report `QMAKE_HOST.arch` as `armv7l`, while older board\OS can report `armv6l`.

while 64bit builds, like UbuntuMate for RaspberryPi: `aarch64`

Answer (score 1):

```
contains(QMAKESPEC,.*linux-rasp-pi\d*-.*){
   message(rpi)
   CONFIG += rpi
   DEFINES += RASPBERRY_PI
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
It's look like no one has an answer, so I did a workaround that works for me and I will happy if it works for you.

at the time to execute qmake I aggregate one flag, for example

```
qmake CONFIG+=MQ_ARM -r
```

It will execute qmake recursive and pass the flag to each .pro file.

In the .pro file you can add this:

```
MQ_ARM {
    LIBS +=bla bla
    message(USING ARM LIBRARY)
} else:MQ_i686 {
    LIBS +=bla bla
    message(USING 32bits LIBRARY)
}
else {
    LIBS +=bla bla bla
    message(qmake configurated as x86_64 if you want another conf use qmake CONFIG+=MQ_ARM project.pro -
}
```

You can separate into another file project.pri and include in all subproject .pro files with include(project.pri)

Hope it helps!